# C# TCP/IP Client Server fake ip address

Tags: c#, sockets, client, server

I have a server which is listening on a port. Now I want to do some stress testing with C# TCPClient by sending multiple clients and messages asynchronously. I want to assign the tcpclient an ip address, but i can only assign the ip address that is bound to my machine. Is there any way to create a fake tcpclient?

Comment: Typically, the server listens on a specific port and for every connection it will create a unique port for that connection. This means that you can start as many clients as you like on your local machine, each will have its own port.

Comment: i need to connect different ips, if i do what ur saying that would just be different objects with same instace

Comment: Why should it matter?  IP address is only relevant as part of a socket-pair of IP/port.  Like @Emile says, just use loads of local clients.  That's what I do for load-testing and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using raw sockets. See [Socket Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx)